# How to include Javascript and CSS files with Express.js

Tags: html, node.js, express

I have a simple node server running in a file called page.js just as a test of a system I am trying to setup.  In that file I have the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/Users/JohnFarkerson/Documents/SublimeFolder/index.html');
});

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.send("404 –– Page not found");
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
});
```

That path to the index file leads to the same directory (SublimeFolder) as the .js file is saved in.  Also in that directory are my javascript and css files. Within index.html, I have the following lines:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyleSheet.css">
```

I have tried changing those paths within index.html to the full path on my computer, but that didn't solve my problem.  When I find the index.html file in Finder and double click, it opens `file:///Users/JohnFarkerson/Documents/SublimeFolder/index.html` in Chrome, which looks perfect.  However, when I run the server in node and then go to http://localhost:8080/, the page loads a very bare-bones version without any of my javascript or css.  What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

It now works.  index.html looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/Users/JohnFarkerson/Documents/SublimeFolder/index.html');
});

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.send("404 –– Page not found");
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First place javascript file in js folder then copy this code in app.js (main node.js file):

```
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
```

Comment: I tried adding both `app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname, + '/js'));` and `app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname, + '/css'));` but nothing changed.  Anything else I need to do?

Comment: Did you place those myscript.js file to js folder?

Comment: Yes, I put myscript.js in a folder called "js" located in the SublimeFolder and myStyleSheet.css in a folder called "css".  Now it doesn't even work by double clicking it in finder.

Comment: If you would like to you can send your files to my mailid : dalchandkumawat9@gmail.com I can check and send the corrected one.

Comment: Wait, should I still be accessing the files in index like `src="myScript.js"` or do I need to change that part to `src="/js/myScript.js"` or something like that?

Comment: Here's something strange, when I run on localhost, and go to javascript console, the files seem to show up in the filesystem but when I click on them I get "404 file not found" in the console.

Comment: isntead of src="/js/..." try src="js/..."

Comment: Nope, still nothing sadly

Comment: Hahahaha turns out somehow I got a comma in there accidentally:  `app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname, + '/js'));`  Working now, thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 0):

If you open `file:///Users/JohnFarkerson/Documents/SublimeFolder/index.html` in Chrome, the protocol is file protocol.  But if you open `http://localhost:8080/`, it's a http protocol. The express create a http server. The `.html` `.css` and `.js` files are static files of http server.

Maybe your directory look like this:

```
SublimeFolder
|--- index.html
|--- myScript.js
|--- myStyleSheet.css
```

In a file protocol, you use absolute path in your disk, the root path is `/`, so it works fine.

But in a http protocol, the root path is http server root, may it will defined in your code, such as:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The http server root is `your_project_path/public`, and you should put your js and css files in `your_project_path/public` directory, and then use root path to link theme. For example, the public directory structure is:

```
your_project_path/public
|--- myScript.js
|--- myStyleSheet.css
```

And the `script` tag is `<script src="/myScript.js"></script>`.

You can use [Express application generator](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to create an express project, and check the project structure, then you could understand it.